Using PySpark Structured Streaming, How to Send Processed Data to Client Through WebSocket
I'm using on a PySpark Structured Streaming in my application where I use readStream to read appended data from an Apache Iceberg table. After processing the data within the PySpark framework, I want to send the processed data to a WebSocket client using the websockets library in Python.
I tried using .foreach(), but I could not use await inside it

I found a solution:

Define the asynchronous processing function:

async def process(df, df_id, websocket):
    # data processing
    await websocket.send(data)


Create a wrapper function to process each batch of streaming data:

def process_wrapper(batch_df, batch_id, websocket):
    asyncio.run(process(batch_df, batch_id, websocket))


Set up the streaming query:

query = df \
       .writeStream \
       .outputMode("append") \
       .foreachBatch(partial(process_wrapper, websocket=websocket)) \
       .trigger(processingTime="10 seconds") \
       .start()

